# Add controller name on makefile command

Tags: symfony, makefile

I am a junior developer and I am currently making a makefile for my project. I would have liked to know if there would be the possibility of passing an argument like the name for a controller.
for example under Symfony in normal times I would execute the command:

```
Symfony console make: controller "controller name"
```

and my controller would be automatically created and named in one line.

Comment: I don't know what Symfony is so I can't interpret your example.  If you provided an example of a makefile rule we may be able to help.  Generally, you can set variables on the command line, such as `make CONTROLLER="controller name"`

Answer (score 2):

`symfony console make:controller ConferenceController`

find more info at [the-fast-track](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/6-controller.html)

Comment: That is not actually what they are asking.  It is a confusing question.  They seem to want to know how to run the command from a makefile which is a bit bizarre to say the least.